# How to split string in a variable without loosing spaces?

Tags: string, parsing, batch-file, split, space

how can i split the string

```
"   This  is  a text  with  spaces    "
```

that is in the variable "string"
into text parts without loosing the spaces ?

```
set string="#   This  is  a text  with  spaces    #"
```

should be split into

```
"#   This"
"  is"
"  a"
" text"
"  with"
"  spaces    #"
```

Using  `For /F "delims= " ...`  doesn't work because it eliminates all spaces.

Is there a 'simple' solution or can anyone explain how to parse the string character by character
so i can count up spaces to first character, then read all characters until next space and write
the counted spaces and the read characters together to a new/temp variable ??

thanks

Comment: What have the `#`s got to do with the matter? they seem to appear from thin air.

Comment: The # is to show the beginning and end of the string. But that doesn't matter because a string can also contain this # at the beginning and/or end.

Comment: Actually, it's very important - and still doesn't explain your output. I'll conclude you want to start a new substring at each space-sequence; but that would make your first substring `#` and second `   This`;your second-last `  spaces` and your last `    #` - which is different from your posted result.

Comment: First two & last two strings must be treated separately. This makes the question more complicated.

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, I don't really understand the `#` either.  What is it about **"    spaces    #"** that makes it hold onto the trailing spaces, while all other elements keep the preceding but not the proceeding spaces?

Oh, well, effort spent in asking = effort spent in answering.  Do with this what you will.

```
@if (@a==@b) @end /*

:: batch portion

@echo off
setlocal

call :split "#   This  is  a text  with  spaces    #"
exit /b

:split <string>
cscript /nologo /e:jscript "%~f0" "%~1"
goto :EOF

:: JScript portion */
WSH.Echo(WSH.Arguments(0).match(/\s*\S+/g).join('\n'));
```

Output:

```
#
   This
  is
  a
 text
  with
  spaces
    #
```

---

#### Update

If you want the first + second, and the penultimate + ultimate elements joined, modify the JScript portion of the above script as follows:

```
:: JScript portion */
var m = WSH.Arguments(0).match(/\s*\S+/g);
m[0] = m.shift() + m[0];
m[m.length - 2] += m.pop();
WSH.Echo(m.join('\n'));
```

Output:

```
#   This
  is
  a
 text
  with
  spaces    #
```

And if you want each element enclosed in quotation marks, change the last line as follows:

```
    WSH.Echo('"' + m.join('"\n"') + '"');
```

Output:

```
"#   This"
"  is"
"  a"
" text"
"  with"
"  spaces    #"
```

Comment: The **"    spaces    #"** has trailing spaces because either the first word or the last word will have spaces on both sides.

Comment: So you want it split the way I have it, but the first + second and the penultimate + last elements joined.  OK.  I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see a simple solution in batch, though of course if you can consider powershell or javascript you'll be working with a more appropriate toolset for string manipulation.

Sticking with the batch requirement, you can loop through character by character and "collect" your words with something like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "string=   This  is  a text  with  spaces    "

set idx=0
set "word="
set "char="
set "lastchar= "
:loop
if "!string:~%idx%!" equ "" goto :eof
set char=!string:~%idx%,1!
if "%char%" equ " " (
    if "%lastchar%" neq " " (
        echo [%word%]
        set word=%char%
    ) else (
        set word=%word%%char%
    )
) else (
    set word=%word%%char%
)
set lastchar=%char%
set /a idx=%idx%+1
goto loop
```

This script uses batch's substring feature `!string:~%idx%,1` to grab a single character from the string, incrementing `idx` with each loop.  Then it's just a matter of processing the word (`echo` in this example) when the previous character was not a space and the current one is.

This writes out:

```
[   This]
[  is]
[  a]
[ text]
[  with]
[  spaces]
```

Note that I'm ignoring the `#` you had in your example because I don't understand where they fit in.

Answer (score 2):

the trick is substituting the contiguous spaces by just one space and the rest by some arbitrary character. Assuming your string does not contain `#`s and that there are no more than 9 contiguous spaces, you can try this

```
set st=%st:         = ########%
set st=%st:        = #######%
set st=%st:       = ######%
set st=%st:      = #####%
set st=%st:     = ####%
set st=%st:    = ###%
set st=%st:   = ##%
set st=%st:  = #%
```

then you may parse with `for /f` and substitute back your `#`s by spaces

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f %%a in ("%st%") do (
  set ss= %%a
  echo !ss:#= !
)
```

note that `set` inside the parentheses block requires you to enable delayed expansion and to use the `!` syntax (see `HELP SET`)

But this technique will only extract the first substring. To generalize, you need another trick, that is substituting the spaces into newlines so that the `for /f` will loop kinda line by line

note that in order to obtain a newline char you need to preserve the two blank lines after the `set` command

```
set nl=^


rem continue two lines down....
for /f %%a in ("%st: =!nl!%") do (
  set ss= %%a
  set ss=!ss:#= !
  echo [!ss!]
)
```

Comment: +1, Nice answer as long as the number of consecutive spaces is reasonably constrained. I've written a more general search and replace based solution that relies on a minimal number of GOTOs. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16072441/1012053)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
@echo off &setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "string=#   This  is  a text  with  spaces    #"

set string1=%string%
for %%i in (%string%) do (
    set string1=!string1: %%i = "%%i" !
    set /a strings+=1
)
set string1=#"%string1:~1,-1%"#
set string1=%string1:"= "%
for %%i in (%string1%) do (
    set /a count+=1
    set string2=%%i
    set string2=!string2: "=!
    set string2=!string2:"=!
    if !count! equ 2 (
     set $s1=!$s1!!string2!
    )else if !count! equ %strings% (
        set /a count-=1
        call set $s!count!=%%$s!count!%%!string2!
        ) else set $s!count!=!string2!
)
for /f "tokens=1*delims==" %%i in ('set "$s"') do echo "%%j"
```

Output:

```
"#   This"
"  is"
"  a"
" text"
"  with"
"  spaces    #"
```

Answer (score 2):

If I had to accomplish this obscure task, I would use a hybrid JScript/batch technique like in [rojo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16069645/1012053). However, I would use a [REPL.BAT utility that I have already written](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3855). Assuming my REPL.BAT is in either the current folder, or else somewhere in the PATH, then the following will work:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "string=#   This  is  a text  with  spaces    #"

:: Build an "array" of text parts
set cnt=0
for /f delims^=^ eol^= %%A in ('repl "([^ ])(?= )" "$1\n" xs string') do (
  set /a cnt+=1
  set "string!cnt!=%%A"
)

:: Print the array values
for /l %%N in (1 1 %cnt%) do echo string%%N=[!string%%N!]
```

But if I wanted a pure batch solution, I would use the fairly efficient method below:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "string=#   This  is  a text  with  spaces    #"

:: Define LF to contain a single line feed character (0x0A)
set LF=^


:: Above 2 blank lines are critical - DO NOT REMOVE


:: Insert a line feed before every space
for %%n in ("!LF!") do set "string=!string: =%%~n !"

:loop  Remove line feeds sandwiched by spaces
for %%n in ("!LF!") do set "string2=!string: %%~n =  !"
if "!string2!" neq "!string!" (
  set "string=!string2!"
  goto :loop
)

:: Build an "array" of text parts: FOR /F splits the string at line feeds
set /a cnt=0
for /f delims^=^ eol^= %%A in ("!string!") do (
  set /a cnt+=1
  set "string!cnt!=%%A"
)

:: Print out the array values
for /l %%N in (1 1 %cnt%) do echo string%%N=[!string%%N!]
```

Both solutions above give the following output:

```
string1=[#]
string2=[   This]
string3=[  is]
string4=[  a]
string5=[ text]
string6=[  with]
string7=[  spaces]
string8=[    #]
```

Note that the FOR loop `%%A` expansion will corrupt the results if the string contains `!` due to delayed expansion. This limitation can be eliminated with additional coding. All the other posted solutions that use a FOR loop suffer from this same limitation. (at least they did when I wrote this)